# tmp file exists for some ms, will it be written to SSD?

Tags: python, linux, file-io

Is a file stored to disc, when only present for a fraction of a second?
I'm running with python 3.7 on ubuntu 18.04.

I make use of a python script. This script extracts json-files from a zip-package. Resulting files will be processed. Afterwards the resulting files well be deleted.

As I'm running on an SSD. I want to spare write cycles to it.

Does linux buffer such write cycles to the RAM, or do I need to assume, that I'm forcing my poor SSD into sever thousend write cycles per second?

Answer (score 1):

Linux may cache file operations under some circumstances, but you're looking for it to optimize by avoiding ever committing a whole sequence of operations to storage at all, based on there being no net effect.  I do not think you can expect that.

It sounds like you might be better served by using a different filesystem in the first place.  Linux has memory-backed file systems (served by the tmpfs filesystem driver, for example), so perhaps you want to set up such a filesystem for your application to use for these scratch files.<sup>1</sup>  Do note, however, that these are backed by *virtual* memory, so, although this approach should reduce the number of write cycles on your SSD, it might not eliminate all writes.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66331/289373